# Create count tables for multiple variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
 Indicator       A1        B1      C1      A2     B2      C2      D2    E2    A3    B3    C3
 Control         0         1        0       3      3      2       0      1    0     4      1
 Control         1         1        2       3      2      0       1      3    2     1      0
Treatment        2         0        1       3      3      4       2      4    0     2      2
```

And so on for about 100 observations. These are ratings from 0-4. I'd like to create a frequency table that includes frequencies of 0-4 across all variables (A1, B1 etc) grouped by Indicator. I only know that table() function but it takes only two arguments. Here, I'd like three groupings.

Additionally, there are more variables in my dataset (named along the same lines like H1, H2, J3, J4 etc.) and more are likely to be added. Ideally the code should accommodate these.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data in long format and then use `count` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Indicator) %>%
  count(Indicator, name, value)
```